# Namespace for my project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What namespace i should to add for my project?

At this moment i get this error "Partial declarations of WPFApplication3.method must not specify different base classes"

Below is my code:

Code Method.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.method"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="method" Height="300" Width="300">

//some code

 </Window>
```

Code Method.cs:

```
 namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for method.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class method : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public method()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: It's just what the error message says. In your xaml you have a `Window` but in your code it's `MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: By the way, .NET naming conventions stipulate that types (classes, structs, etc) should have `PascalCase` capitalization.

Answer (score 2):

Change your **Base class** in .cs file to `Window`

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for method.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class method : Window
    {
        public method()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a base class of `MonoBehavior` in your code-behind, you'll need to change your XAML accordingly, to specify the same base class.

Change this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.method" ... >
```

To this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MonoBehavior" ... >
```